# Pie chart for cluster points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clustering, chart

I have a point layer that I generated from a table with dresses using Geocode in the MMGIS plugin. In the attribute table I have several columns. I am interested in the column called "Factor". There I categorized each point by a factor (which is a name, and I have a total of 10).

Because a lot of points were overlapping on my map, I clustered them (to get a sense how much points I have in each region) but I want to display the factors in a pie chart to show in each cluster, what is the proportion of points with factor1, factor2, factor3, ...

How can I do this?

(Also, side note, but when I used the clustering method, I lost all the single points that were not clustered. I now have to have 2 layers, one for the clusters and another one underneath with all the points to also show the single points; is there a way to show the single points in the layer with the clusters?)

Comment: Each cluster have a unique attribute?

Comment: What clustering method did you use? Some enable you to store the non-clustered points in the same layer.

Comment: @BERA I'm not sure I see what you mean... I'm sorry I'm very new at this... But if I open the attribute table for my point layer, each lign is a point...

Comment: @MarcM I went into Properties > Symbology > Point cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you defined your regions for clustering, but use `DBSCAN clustering`. Define the minimum cluster size and max distance between points. This could be linked to your regions.

The output will be an vector layer containing the original features with a field setting the cluster they belong to. With this information you know the number of points in a cluster and the number of factor1, factor2 etc inside this cluster.

Next, a pie chart can be generated by going to Properties > Diagrams > Diagram type: Pie chart.